# C# programatically use different network card IP's assigned to a PC

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, dynamic, ip

I have 3 network cards which are assigned to my PC, and I was wondering if there is a way to programatically use these IP's at my own will ?

I have done some research on this topic but I haven't understood it quite well..

P.S. guys all of these 3 network cards have 3 different public IP's ...

Is there a way that I can pick through which IP I want to connect?

If there is a way, can someone help me out ?

Comment: In what context? Receiving connections? Making outgoing connections?

Comment: @DavidG making outgoing connection and receiving a response....

Comment: @DavidG Basically a http request => response with an IP from my network cards that I want

Comment: How are you making the HTTP requests?

Comment: @DavidG a simple good old httpwebrequest ^^